# Expressing Probability Joint Events

Tags: probability-theory

For two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have possible integer values from $1$ to $10$. To be identically distributed, the joint distribution $F(x,y)$ must be $0.01$ for all values through the sample space.

My question is that is this the right way to write it?

$$
F_{x,y}(x,y) = 0.01 \quad\forall\>\>(x,y)=1,2,\cdots,10
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X=x,Y=y)$ is the joint probability function, then you could write it as a bracket:
$$
p_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
1/100,\quad& (x,y)\in\{1,2,\ldots,10\}^2,\\
0,&\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
or in terms of indicator functions
$$
p_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{100}\mathbf1_{(x,y)\in\{1,\ldots,10\}^2}.
$$
The last method is a version of the Iverson bracket used in Sasha's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A correct way to write it would be
$$
   \Pr(X=x, Y=y) = \frac{1}{100} [ 1 \leqslant x \leqslant 10] \cdot [ 1 \leqslant y \leqslant 10]
$$
where $[ \bullet ]$ denotes the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).